# it’s a pleasure meeting you or it’s pleasure meeting you.Why do we put the article’a’ when pleasure is an abstract and uncountable noun?

Tags: grammar, articles, nouns, spoken-english, uncountable-nouns

How to use uncountable nouns as countable nouns? Here pleasure is abstract noun and how to identify uncountable nouns as countable nouns according to situations?

Comment: Obviously it's ***not*** an uncountable noun in the cited context, any more than [*XXX is one of life's little **pleasures***,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+one+of+life%27s+little+pleasures%22) which is an extremely common way of referring to one's specific "vice" (which can *also* be either countable or uncountable). Note that idiomatically it ***is*** usually *a pleasure **to meet** you*, not ***...meeting** you* - unless you're "taking leave", where *It **has been** a pleasure meeting you* is reasonable enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your question starts from a false premise. Yes, "pleasure" can be used as an abstract noun which is not countable. But "pleasure" can also be used as a concrete noun representing acts that give pleasure in the abstract sense.

> Eating chocolate ice cream with a friend under a shady tree on a hot day is one of life's simple pleasures.
>
> Come live with me and be my love,/ And we will all the pleasures prove/
>   That valleys, groves, hills, and fields,/ Woods and steepy mountain yields.